# Compile Application with local files

Tags: wpf

So I have a word template that I am trying to populate within my wpf application. It works fine during development. However, when I try to edit the file after publishing/installing the application it no longer has the folder/files that were used in the development process.

What steps do I need to take to have files present after installation to manipulate, create, or delete files?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the file in VS Solution Explorer, then in file properties set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy Always`

Answer (score 1):

Add that template as content in your solutions. You will find this from properties.